# RASPBERRY PI 3 B+ internet access problem

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, wifi, internet

A static Ip has been given for my raspberry pi from my company. That means if a connected to my office wifi network in anytime, the ip is 172.16.100.13

I have not changed anything in my Pi. Any static ip or something. It has newly installed raspbian os. But I CANNOT ACCESS THE INTERNET with my office wifi network. If I active a hotspot from my mobile phone & connect raspberry pi with that hotspot, I can access internet (can ping to anywhere). With company's wifi network I only can ping to ip addresses which are connected to my company's wifi network.(Eg. to my laptop. not to google).

But my laptop also got an ip which is same as the ip given to the PI by the company. It is 172.16.20.77
But I can access internet and every thing with my laptop. Only raspberry pi cannot access internet with company's wifi network. Both mac addresses have been added to company's wifi network. My laptop is also running on linux.

What is the reason for this problem & how can I solve this?????

Comment: Can you ping (NOT browse) www.google.com from your laptop?

Comment: Many corporate networks block pings on their network, so it's likely the connection works fine despite your pings failing.

Comment: Also many corporate networks do not allow direct access to the internet, or only allow certain ports (or even protocols) through - you have to go through a proxy for the rest, if one is available, or you can't use it at all. You need a baseline with a known-working device to understand _exactly_ what you can expect to work, before introducing your new, untested device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry pi3 model B+ connect to wifi but no internet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/raspberry-pi3-model-b-connect-to-wifi-but-no-internet)

Comment: I can ping to www.google.com from my laptop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't ask nearly the same question a second time! You have just asked 4 hours ago that question but with modified `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you changed that then please edit and explain it in your first question: [Raspberry pi3 model B+ connect to wifi but no internet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95335/79866).

The answer I have given there (look at it) is also valid for this question: edit `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and setup your static entries. And again: you should better use DHCP like your Laptop. Then it will also work like it without problems.

B.t.w.: Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: I did the modifications of dhcpcd.conf. But it does not works